# Aggregate/Sum function on a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am having issues aggregating/summing up the output of a query (subquery?). Here is my initial code and output:

code:

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SELECT
AsOfDate,
round(ColA/sum(ColB) * (ColC),4) As 'Monthly_Return'
from xyz.abc
WHERE
AsOfDate BETWEEN '2021-05-25' AND '2021-05-26'
and ColD like '123%'
GROUP BY AsOfDate, ColA,ColB,ColC



|   AsOfDate |MarketV(ColA)|MarketV(ColB)|Return(ColC)|(ColD)|
|------------|-------------|-------------|------------|------|
| 2021-05-25 |   8891171.14|   8891171.14| -0.81166911|   123|
| 2021-05-25 |  14219713.92|  14219713.92|  2.12135625|   123|
| 2021-05-25 |   3102248.42|   3102248.42|  0.36907554|   123|
| 2021-05-26 |   8819004.25|   8819004.25|  0.88822511|   123|
| 2021-05-26 |  14521364.71|  14521364.71|  1.84104756|   123|
| 2021-05-26 |   3113698.06|   3113698.06|  0.44211577|   123|

|The sum of ColB for 2021-05-25 is 26,213,133.48|


|The sum of ColB for 2021-05-25 is 26,454,067.02|
```

I want the sum of ColAi/ColB * ColCi grouped by date.

```
|For 2021-05-25                              |  Return |
|--------------------------------------------|---------|
|8891171.14 / 26,213,133.48 * -0.81166911   =|-0.275308|
|14219713.92 / 26,213,133.48 * 2.12135625   =|1.150762 |
|3102248.42 / 26,213,133.48 * 0.36907554    =|0.043679 |

|For 2021-05-26                              |  Return |
|--------------------------------------------|---------|
|8819004.25 / 26,454,067.02 * 0.88822511    =|0.296108 |
|14521364.71 / 26,454,067.02 * 1.84104756   =|1.0106016|
|3113698.06 / 26,454,067.02 * 0.44211577    =|0.0520379|
```

My current code is shows the following output:

| AsOfDate | Monthly_Return |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-25 | -0.275308 |
| 2021-05-25 | 1.150762 |
| 2021-05-25 | 0.043679 |
| 2021-05-26 | 0.296108 |
| 2021-05-26 | 1.0106016 |
| 2021-05-26 | 0.0520379 |

What I really want is this:

| AsOfDate | Monthly_Return |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-25 | 0.9191 |
| 2021-05-26 | 1.3587 |

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY AsOfDate` or `GROUP BY AsOfDate, ColumnA`.

Comment: What does `sum(ColumnB)` represent in your mind?  Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: sum(ColumnB) is the sum of all values in columnB by date

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS in question. `As 'Monthly_Return'` is invalid according to the SQL standard for instanmce, because single quotes are reserved for string literals, not for names. `AsOfDate BETWEEN '2021-05-25' AND '2021-05-26'` can fail in some DBMS, because you are using string literals here instead of date literals.

Comment: So is `Monthly_Return` a fraction of `SUM(ColumnB)` for the [filtered] query results or the entire table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query really gives you the sub results you are after, then all you have to do is put the query in a subquery and aggregate again:

```
SELECT
  asofdate,
  SUM(monthly_return)
FROM ( <your query here> ) subquery
GROUP BY asofdate
ORDER BY asofdate;
```

As it is kind of rare that you are grouping by all columns you are selecting, I am showing you some sample data and the results, so you can double check:

With this data

| AsOfDate | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-25 | 12 | 2 | 3 | 123 |
| 2021-05-25 | 12 | 2 | 3 | 123 |
| 2021-05-25 | 12 | 2 | 3 | 123 |
| 2021-05-25 | 12 | 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 2021-05-25 | 12 | 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 2021-05-25 | 12 | 1 | 3 | 123 |

your query will get

| AsOfDate | Monthly_Return |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-25 | 6 |
| 2021-05-25 | 12 |

and the final aggregation makes this

| AsOfDate | SUM(Monthly_Return) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-25 | 18 |

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3e2907d96baa1c73e29f223c0cf7edc2

### UPDATE

According to your last edit you merely want:

```
SELECT asofdate, SUM(columna * columnc) * 1.0 / SUM(columnb)
FROM xyz.abc
WHERE asofdate BETWEEN '2021-05-25' AND '2021-05-26'
AND columnd LIKE '123%'
GROUP BY asofdate
ORDER BY asofdate;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2b40e9cb83a22c8cc5831b16e61ffca

The multiplication with 1.0 can be necessary in SQL Server for otherwise it may inappropriately apply integer division here (depending on your data types).

If you rather want to work with intermediate results, here is your query corrected:

```
SELECT
  asofdate,
  ROUND(cola * 1.0 / SUM(colb) OVER (PARTITION BY asofdate) * colc, 4) AS monthly_return
from xyz.abc
WHERE asofdate BETWEEN '2021-05-25' AND '2021-05-26'
AND cold LIKE '123%';
```

As mentioned you can use this in a subquery to get the final result.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82b3977d5b0591fe0a2b5bc65b3dab34

Comment: Monthly_return is an alias

Comment: @OnTheHunt: Yes. So what?

Comment: i'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management. Could that be the reason your suggestion isn't working for me?

I want ColumnAi / Sum of ColumnB * ColumnCi

Then aggregating everything in the end

Comment: Thorsten Kettner, based on your table data, the result I expect is 24 not 18. We want 12/9*3=4. When we add up the results from each row then we should get 24.

Comment: 12 / 9 * 3? Let's see, 9 is the sum of all B values, right? And 12 is what? The average of all A values or the maximum or the minimum? Same for 3, is this the average or minimum or maximum of the C values or what else? Define this t get the formula straight. You may be fighting an inappropriate data model here, by the way. Maybe you want to explain what the table and the columns really represent, so we may help on that. ColumnA, etc. are names that don't help understanding your data.

Comment: The query runs just the same in SQL Server: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4802f13aca803f89741f1a36532736b5, Only your initial requirement to add up your intermediate results has turned out wrong.

Comment: I've updated my question. It should be a lot more clear now

Comment: Okay, so you no longer want to add up your results, because they can be wrong, but apply the formula ∑(A*C) / ∑B for each day. That is simple. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Completely rewritten with your new requirements and new column names.  (For what it's worth, since you've already selected an answer.)

```
with a as (
  select AsOfDate
  , ColA
  , sum(ColB) over (partition by AsOfDate) as ColB
  , ColC
  from abc
  where AsOfDate BETWEEN '2021-05-25' AND '2021-05-26'
    and ColD like '123%'
)

select AsOfDate
, cast(round(sum(ColA * ColC / ColB), 4) as decimal(6,4)) as 'Monthly_Return'
from a
group by AsOfDate
;
```

Maybe next time, include a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3ff7784929d5f649a696e4206cdbee2) in your question so your structure and data is available.  Also, include your desired outcome when you first ask the question.

Comment: Grouping by only the AsOfDate doesn't work. Here's the error it gives:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
Column 'xyz.abc.ColumnA' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
Column 'xyz.abc.ColumC' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I revised my answer to accommodate that, but it's really a guess since your question is unclear.  `GROUP BY AsOfDate` means "Group them by date".  What do you really mean?

Comment: I've updated my question showing the output i'm currently getting

Comment: You already posted the output.  What would be more helpful is sample input and **desired** output.

Comment: your suggestion works when i remove the date range (BETWEEN...AND...) and only focus on one day, such as AsOfDate = 2021-05-25. It looks like the date range is causing it to sum up everything between the dates, but i want the calculation to be grouped by date

Comment: i've updated my question according to your suggestion. It should be clear now.

Comment: I have updated my answer to answer the new question.